# Configuring Serilog File with web.config

Tags: c#, serilog

I'm trying to configure Serilog for a .NET FW 4.7.1 project. Here's what I have in my web.config:

**Problem**: `serilog:write-to:File.outputTemplate` is not working

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug" />

    <add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
    <!--<add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="C:\Logs" />--> (This will be dynamically generate, Per User)
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.outputTemplate" value="{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u4}] | ({**AppName**}) | {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.shared" value="true" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollingInterval" value="Day"/>

    <add key="serilog:enrich:with-property:AppName" value="MyApp" />
</appSettings>
```

In Code,

```
 var userlogPath =  Path.Combine("C:\Logs", $"User_{UserId}_.log"); // Logged in **UserId** will be passed.

 var logger = Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
      .WriteTo.File(userlogPath)
      .CreateLogger();
```

`logger.Information("Test Log");` // It's not considering **outputTemplate** from Web.Config. Not logging `AppName` as well.

Comment: Just a note that didn't really belong in the answer - using `WriteTo.File()` in code will very likely turn out better for your use case; enriching logs with the logged-in user id, and using [_Serilog.Sinks.Map_](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map) to route log events to files based on the added property, should be more efficient and robust than manually creating per-user log files. HTH!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to mix the XML configuration with the `WriteTo.File()` in code.

Either the `File.path` needs to be specified in XML (as you've shown, commented out), or, the other settings like `File.outputTemplate` need to be supplied to `WriteTo.File()`.

Comment: It's not possible to mix. Thanks for answer.